# mysql like operator doesn't give appropriate result

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Suppose we have software engineer, software developer, project engineer in a column in mysql table..

And if we execute 
**select * from tbl_name where col_name like '%software engineer%'**

then it is showing one record which is software engineer

But i want both record software engineer & software developer

Then what should be the query to get both record if we put software engineer in like field

Comment: Please take the [tour] that was provided to you when you made an account and read [ask]

Comment: Of course you don't find `software developer`, if you instruct the database to look for anything that contains `software engineer`. If you want to find both if the search term entered is `software engineer` , then you need to look for either of those terms separately.

Answer (score 2):

You an do

```
Select * from tbl_name where col_name like '%software %'
```

This way everything with substring "software " will appear.

Comment: When you search job on any portal when you write software engineer in textbox then you get both jobs i.e software engineer and software developer

Comment: You can write software engineer and at the backend of portal write this query if (input=="software enginner" || input=="software developer")

Comment: Suppose you are getting input value in a variable named as "input" then you can do.....(input=="software enginner" || input=="software developer"){input="software "} and can then execute the query mentioned above using "input" instead of "software".

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you write 
 `select * from tbl_name where col_name like '%software%'`. Understand it as this is considering "software" as a substring and finding it in columns.

If you want to match approximate patterns have a look here.  [Matching patterns using LIKE](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1276352&seqNum=7)